# Rebasing workflows: do you always need to rebase first on simple PR's

Tags: git, github

Our team uses a rebase strategy to pull in the latest changes from our staging branch. Is it important to *always* rebase changes from the upstream?

Let's say I have a branch `master`. On it, I've branched into two separate features: `feature1` and `feature2`. Each of the feature branches are working on separate files and there are 0 chances of a merge conflict.

`feature1` branch has progressed and I've made a commit to it. `feature2` branch has also progressed and I've made a commit to it. I want both branches changes into master.

Faking the "PR", I merge `feature1` into master.

Here's the questions:

1. Should I rebase `feature2` onto `master` first? or just merge `feature2` into `master`?
2. Are there any downfalls to just merging here? Rebasing seems like an unnecessary step in this situation since it's just a quick fast-forward.

Comment: You get linear history this way, which some people like. Also if you don't have a build server configured correctly, even if there are no merge conflicts, it doesn't mean the code compiles correctly (although on different files it's less likely), let alone it works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I rebase feature2 onto master first? or just merge feature2 into master?

Always rebase, especially if you are the only one working on `feature2`: the idea is to replay your feature2 commit on the new state on `master` (which now includes `feature1`).

Then you can merge (fast-forward or no-ff, as you want): the merge won't have any conflict because you will have solve them locally first. And you would have tested (again, locally) if feature1+feature2 are working together.

Comment: what is the functional difference between rebasing `feature2` onto master(with new `feature1` changes) then merging versus just merging `feature2`. Mainly, what are the major downfalls of the latter? just a less linear history?

Comment: @AndrewKim Generally, you don't push your own master directly, you are pushing branches, which are then merged to master on the remote side through pull request/merge request. And if that branch was rebased on top of master first, that request is easy to process. If you can push master directly though, then yes: merge every feature branch in your local master, make your integration tests pass, and push.